# PHP IMAP sync a folder

Tags: php, imap

I am building the PHP application to sync IMAP mailbox with local copy.
I need to find a way to load only messages from IMAP folders that i didn't load yet.

PHP IMAP library has the function imap_search to do something similar.
For example, imap_search($conn, 'SINCE "8 August 2012"', SE_UID);

However, this solution doesn't work well. Often emails have wrong date (can be future date) and sync works wrong.

What is the best practice to do sync with IMAP server from PHP? How to load real list of messages i didn't load yet?
For now i can see only one way to do this - loads IDs fo all emails on IMAP server and compare with list if IDs saved locally.
Is there better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fetch from lowest UID to highest UID (and new messages in the folder always have a higher UID than any previous message), then you can do a search for `UID <uid>:*`, where uid is one more than the highest UID you currently have.

Comment: +1 I believe the spec requires the UIDs on the server to be monotonically increasing.

Comment: Are you sure all IMAP servers have UIDs as integers?  For me it seems some servers can have IDs as unique text code . but i am not sure about this.

Comment: No, the IMAP specification indicates that UIDs are always increasing integers.  POP3 servers may have text uids.

Answer (score 0):

I found the description of UID in IMAP specifications

"A 32-bit value assigned to each message, which when used with the    unique identifier validity value (see below) forms a 64-bit value  that MUST NOT refer to any other message in the mailbox or any subsequent mailbox with the same name forever.  Unique identifiers are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the mailbox; as each message is added to the mailbox it is assigned a higher UID than the message(s) which were added previously.  Unlike message sequence numbers, unique identifiers are not necessarily contiguous."

So i can remember last processed UID and load only messages with bigger UID.

Comment: You will also have to consider changes of ``UIDVALIDITY``.